# Anchor in TikZ Split Parts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a singly-linked list using TikZ. My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzset{
 anode/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size = 12pt, inner sep = 4pt},
 snode/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=18pt, inner sep=4pt, text=black},
>=Stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\node[snode, on chain] (1) {25};
\node[snode, on chain] (2) {19};
\node[snode, on chain] (3) {41};
\node[snode, on chain] (4) {13};
\node[anode] [above of=1, yshift=4ex] (f) {};
\node[anode] [above of=4, yshift=4ex] (l) {};
\node [left of=f] (fl) {first};
\node [right of=l] (ll) {last};
\draw[*->] (1.two) -- (2);
\draw[*->] (2.two) -- (3);
\draw[*->] (3.two) -- (4);
\draw[*->] (f.mid) -- (1);
\draw[*->] (l.mid) -- (4);
\draw[fill=black] (4.two) circle (2.3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results in the following output:

[image: Output of the MWE]

How can I center all of the filled circles within the rectangles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the center of the second part of a split node via

```
(<node>.two west-|<node>.two south)
```

If you draw arrows, the arrow head will end at the start or target, so you may want to shorten the circle arrows by the corresponding negative amount.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzset{
 anode/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size = 12pt, inner sep = 4pt},
 snode/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, 
 rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=18pt, inner sep=4pt, text=black},
>=Stealth,
carr/.style={{Circle[width=4.6pt,length=4.6pt]}->,shorten <=-2.3pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\node[snode, on chain] (1) {25};
\node[snode, on chain] (2) {19};
\node[snode, on chain] (3) {41};
\node[snode, on chain] (4) {13};
\node[anode] [above of=1, yshift=4ex] (f) {};
\node[anode] [above of=4, yshift=4ex] (l) {};
\node [left of=f] (fl) {first};
\node [right of=l] (ll) {last};
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,3,4}
\draw[carr] (\Y.two west-|\Y.two south) -- (\X);
\draw[carr] (f.center) -- (1);
\draw[carr] (l.center) -- (4);
\draw[fill=black] (4.two west-|4.two south) circle[radius=2.3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may use the same anchors to add some circle nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[anode/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size = 12pt, inner sep = 4pt},
 snode/.style={on chain,rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, 
 rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=18pt, inner sep=4pt, text=black},
>=Stealth,start chain=going right]
\node[snode] (1) {25};
\node[snode] (2) {19};
\node[snode] (3) {41};
\node[snode] (4) {13};
\node[anode] [above of=1, yshift=4ex] (f) {};
\node[anode] [above of=4, yshift=4ex] (l) {};
\node [left of=f] (fl) {first};
\node [right of=l] (ll) {last};
\path [nodes={circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4.6pt}] 
foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
{ (\Y.two west-|\Y.two south) node(c-\Y){}}
(f.center) node(c-0){} (l.center) node(c-5){};
\draw[->] foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,...,3}
{(c-\X) edge (\Y) } (c-5) -- (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, you can make the dots part of the node definition with

```
 append after command={(\tikzlastnode.two west-|\tikzlastnode.two south)
 node[dot] (c-chain-\tikzchaincount) {}}
```

and add the arrows via `join`, `join=by harr`, where

```
 harr/.style={->,to path={(c-\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget)}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[anode/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size = 12pt, inner sep = 4pt},
 dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4.6pt},
 snode/.style={on chain,rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, 
 rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=18pt, inner sep=4pt, text=black,
 append after command={(\tikzlastnode.two west-|\tikzlastnode.two south)
 node[dot] (c-chain-\tikzchaincount) {}},join=by harr},
 harr/.style={->,to path={(c-\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget)}},
    >=Stealth,start chain=going right]
\node[snode] (1) {25};
\node[snode] (2) {19};
\node[snode] (3) {41};
\node[snode] (4) {13};
\node[anode] [above of=1, yshift=4ex,label=left:first,
    label={[anchor=center,dot,name=c-f]center:}] (f) {};
\node[anode] [above of=4, yshift=4ex,label=right:last,
    label={[anchor=center,dot,name=c-l]center:}] (l) {};
\foreach \X/\Y in {f/1,l/4} 
{\draw[->] (c-\X) -- (\Y);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]